# Why Has The Last Key:Value Pair Printed Twice?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

Why has the last key:value pair printed twice when I used a for loop?

```
def values_that_are_keys(my_dictionary):
 for pair in my_dictionary.items():
  print(pair)
 return pair



print(values_that_are_keys({1:100, 2:1, 3:4, 4:10}))

(1, 100)
(2, 1)
(3, 4)
(4, 10)
(4, 10)
```

Comment: you've used `return`..So it will give you an additional

Comment: How many `print` statements do you have? What do you expect each to output and why?

Comment: because I have 2 print statements, why hasn’t everything printed twice?

Comment: Because not everything is being returned, only the last value is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have the `return` statement at the end which returns the last pair and that gets printed extra:

```
return pair  # remove this
```

And call as `values_that_are_keys({1:100, 2:1, 3:4, 4:10})`

Comment: Why does only the last pair get printed extra?

Comment: Because you have the return statement at the end which returns the last pair again after printing all elements in the loop and that gets printed extra, remove the return statement

Comment: Ok thanks. Also one last thing, because I have 2 print statements, why hasn’t everything printed twice?

Comment: Because you return only the last pair which is outside the loop and only that gets printed. Other values are printed within the loop and then it returns the last value after coming out of the loop and so only the last value gets printed. If you move return inside the loop then you will see only first value printed twice since the loop is not executed anymore after return.